# Setting up a web application with an high-availability database or data?

Tags: database, entity-framework, linq, caching, high-availability

I have a web application used by support desk users in the field to manage user accounts. The app uses LINQ queries to programmatically pull data from our database. During recent patching, the database went offline for a few hours, leaving the application useless to support desk users.

I would like to implement a method for data to be available to the app so that if downtime were to occur, queries could still return results. The most successful method I have found so far is by utilizing [EntityFramework.Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus). While this works great for general caching, I still foresee downtime if the database is down when expiring and re-creating the cache to have up-to-date data. I am interested in options other than setting up a second database.

The application:

- Entity Framework 6
- MVC 4
- ~20 users per day
- One database with 6-8 tables and 10-20 rows of data within each table.
- Does not need the ability to write data when database is down, only read.

Given my application's use, what recommendations are there for having data highly available and up-to-date in the case of database downtime? Is a second level cache the way to to go or is there a better way?

Comment: whats the database size ? Seems small enough to fit in memory. Why not just put the database into the same machine ?

Answer (score 0):

If the database is small, you can either cache everything and use the cache as a database fail-over or put the database in the same machine.

If the database is big you'll be unable to cache everything so you need to think about what's the [best cache policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Examples) for your application *then* you can search for a popular caching system that implements this policy or just implement it yourself. I would also recommend you to double check if you don't really need to implement an expiration policy or issue a warning if data is too old.

If you are going to use the cache as both fail-over and as a way to provide faster responses, make sure to keep track of each cache entry timestamp because you'll have to check the cache before trying get data from the database. (you'll only hit the database if the cache isn't fresh anymore)